# Mapping array and create object literals in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays, one is  `const listArray = ["1", "2"]` and another one is `const letterArray = ["a", "b"]`

So result whould be

```
[{value:a, label:a, set1:{value:a, label:a}}, {value:b, label:b, set1:{value:b, label:b}}, {value:a, label:a, set2:{value:a, label:a}}, {value:b, label:b, set2:{value:b, label:b}}]
```

Comment: How is `listArray` related?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Please complete your question by adding the code you have tried so that we may assist you in fixing it.

Comment: map with list array [1, 2, 3, 4] that mean I need four set values

Comment: in const letterArray = [a, b, c, d] what are a, b, c, d? Should not these be 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'???

Comment: ["1", "2"] and ["a", "b"]

Comment: Not to be contrite here but to be direct you have a habit of posting questions without code and/or that show little effort on your part to come up with a solution.  On this site, the requirement is that you create a question that does have code and that shows what you have tried with related question on what you need assistance with for example.
Given your prior questions and this one with just "I need this result" with no code, I am voting to close this (and your other questions like it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code generates the desired output-

```js
const listArray = [1,  2, 3, 4];
const letterArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    
for(var i= 0; i< listArray.length; i++){
  var array = [];
  for(var j=0; j < letterArray.length; j++){
    var letr = letterArray[j];
    var newObj = {
      value: letr, 
      label: letr, 
      ['set'+ listArray[i]]: { value: letr, label: letr }
    };
    array.push(newObj);
  }
console.log(array);  
}
```

Comment: While I do and likely the OP does appreciate your efforts here should we assist this user when they show a continued pattern that does not meet site requirements?